# Parent static method to return subclass object

Tags: javascript, es6-class

```
class Vehicle {
    constructor (name, type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;

        console.log(this.constructor.name);
    }
    getName () {
        return this.name;
    }
    getType () {
        return this.type;
    }
    static create(name, type) {
        return new Vehicle(name, type);
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    constructor (name) {
        super(name, 'car');
    }
    getName () {
        return 'It is a car: ' + super.getName();
    }
}

let car = Car.create('Tesla', 'car');
console.log(car.getName()); // It is a car: Tesla
console.log(car.getType()); // car
```

The above code use ES6 class keyword to define a Vehicle class and a subclass Car from it. How to return Car instance from Vehicle static method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let car = new Car('Tesla')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `ClassName` you want to use within your static function `create` and create an instance from it.

```
static create(name, type, objClass) {
    return new Function(`return new ${objClass ? objClass : 'Vehicle'}('${name}', '${type}');`)();
}
```

The `Function` class receives a String with the expression to evaluate, in your case:

```
new Function(`return new ${objClass}('${name}', '${type}');`)()
```

## Look at this code

```js
class Vehicle {
  constructor(name, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
  }
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  getType() {
    return this.type;
  }
  static create(name, type, objClass) {
    return new Function(`return new ${objClass ? objClass : 'Vehicle'}('${name}', '${type}');`)();
  }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name, 'car');
  }

  getName() {
    return 'It is a car: ' + super.getName();
  }
}

let car = Car.create('Tesla', 'car', 'Car');
console.log(car.getName()); // It is a car: Tesla
console.log(car.getType()); // car

let superCar = Vehicle.create('Tesla', 'car');
console.log(superCar.getName()); // Tesla
console.log(superCar.getType()); // car
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

See? now is printing the right output.

## Resources

- [`Class Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)